# CentOS: Can't add route after deleting the /24 rule from main routing table

Tags: linux, centos, ip, route

As the title says, after deleting a rule from the main routing able I am not able to add any route till I do

```
service network restart
```

or

```
ifup eth0
```

To reproduce the problem:

```
ip route list table main
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.47 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

I can delete and add the default route

```
#ip route del default
#ip route list
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.47 
#ip route add default via 192.168.2.1

#ip route list
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.47 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

However, if I delete the 192.168.2.0/24 route I can't add any route anymore.

```
# ip route del 192.168.2.0/24

# ip route list
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 
# ip route add 192.168.2.0/24
RTNETLINK answers: No such device

# ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 0.0.0.0
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
# ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 src 192.168.2.47
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
# ip route list
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: Why on **earth** would you want to do that?  Is there a business need for this, or are you just asking a question that boils down to "*when I break the routing table, routing stops working*"?

Comment: basically we ship centos on a small pc based device to our customers. Occasionally they do break the routing table by doing something like this. I was wondering if there any way to fix it without rebooting the box.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that you actually have two routing table entries. First there is the default, which points at the gateway 192.168.2.1 in 192.168.2.0/24 network, and then there is the network route for network for interface `eth0` (ie. 192.168.2.0/24) as well.

If you delete the network route of an active, it effectively shuts it down. In this particular case deleting the route 192.168.2.0/24 means you have no usable interfaces for routes and thus adding routes will fail.

Summa summarum: You are simply doing it wrong or at lest in wrong order. Don't delete the 192.168.2.0/24 network, if you have an active interface in that network.

Comment: I question your use of "*happens to be*"; next-hop-route generally *has* to be in the local broadcast network, or you can't use it.

Comment: After reading what I wrote, I agree.

Comment: Fair enough; +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, however, I can't accept the fact that in Linux you can't fix something without reboot.

Comment: That is not at all what is written above. There is no reboot required. Only that whatever you're trying to do is simply not going to work, reboot or not.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got myself the problem.

Basically while adding a route we also need to define the scope and proto as well.

In my case the reason I was not able to add it back because I was not specifying the scope. Scope defined visibility of the IP in the network. It could be host, link [limited to LAN], gloabal etc.

So the correct syntax to add it would be

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 scope link
```